# How is this class's __call__ method working, when it's called without proper arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-3.x, nolearn

I'm going through Daniel Nouri's [tutorial](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/) on facial recognition using CNN's, and I've come across a bit of the code which I don't understand. Daniel is defining a Class to be called at the end of each iteration during the training of the network, that will decide whether or not the training should stop early:

```
class EarlyStopping(object):
    def __init__(self, patience=100):
        self.patience = patience
        self.best_valid = np.inf
        self.best_valid_epoch = 0
        self.best_weights = None

    def __call__(self, nn, train_history):
        current_valid = train_history[-1]['valid_loss']
        current_epoch = train_history[-1]['epoch']
        if current_valid < self.best_valid:
            self.best_valid = current_valid
            self.best_valid_epoch = current_epoch
            self.best_weights = nn.get_all_params_values()
        elif self.best_valid_epoch + self.patience < current_epoch:
            print("Early stopping.")
            print("Best valid loss was {:.6f} at epoch {}.".format(
                self.best_valid, self.best_valid_epoch))
            nn.load_params_from(self.best_weights)
            raise StopIteration()
```

This makes some sense, however the actual implementation in the code looks like:

```
net8 = NeuralNet(
# ...
on_epoch_finished=[
    AdjustVariable('update_learning_rate', start=0.03, stop=0.0001),
    AdjustVariable('update_momentum', start=0.9, stop=0.999),
    EarlyStopping(patience=200),
    ],
# ...
)
```

Clearly, Daniel is calling the class as a function. However, I don't understand how he is calling it without the arguments shown in `__call__(args)`. Is this just how things are meant to be implemented in the source code of nolearn? I'm confused as to how the network knows to use `nn` and `train_history` without those being passed into the function.

Answer (score 4):

He isn't invoking `__call__` with `EarlyStopping(patience=200)`, rather, he's invoking<sup>*</sup> `EarlyStopping.__init__` with a signature of:

```
def __init__(self, patience=100):
```

and providing an alternate value for `patience`; this fully matches the arguments available for `__init__`.

`EarlyStopping.__call__` is invoked *on the instance*; that is, if the sequence of calls was:

```
e = EarlyStopping(patience = 200)
e(patience=50)  # TypeError Raised
```

an appropriate error would be raised.

---

*The parentheses that throw you off *are actually making a call*. The call isn't made to `EarlyStopping.__call__` but to `type.__call__`, the (meta)class of `EarlyStopping`. `type.__call__` is the first action performed by Python when you initialize an object, it gets called accepting any arguments passed and then (after some other actions) calls `__new__` and `__init__` in that order; in essence `__init__` is invoked indirectly with an argument of `patience=100`.

Comment: Ok, so should I presume that the initialized object is then called somewhere in the source code for NeuralNet, with the appropriate arguments? It seems to me like a strange way to implement this feature. Why not just pass a function?